# Aggregate data across dataframes in R

Tags: r

I have two dataframes.  df1 is a dataframe that includes multiple locations within a each set of units.  df2 includes daily observations for maximum temperature (df$tmax) for all locations. For each unit within df1 I would like to compute the average daily max. temperature across all locations within each unit.

The following code generates examples of each dataframe.  I will need to scale this up to about 240 units and 8 years of daily data.

These kind of lookup/matching exercises in R always seem to get me.  There must be an obvious way to do this, but I'm stymied at the moment without some real brute force joining etc.

```r
df1 <- 
structure(list(unitID = c("98008", "98008", "98008", "98008", 
"98065", "98065", "98065", "98065", "98146", "98146", "98146", 
"98146", "98584", "98584", "98584"), locationID = c("USW00094290", "USW00094248", 
"USW00024234", "USC00454169", "USC00458508", "USS0021B60S", "USR0000WFTA", 
"USC00451233", "USW00024234", "USW00024233", "USW00094248", "USC00454169", 
"USW00094227", "USC00451939", "USC00455086")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))

df1
unitID  locationID
1   98008 USW00094290
2   98008 USW00094248
3   98008 USW00024234
4   98008 USC00454169
5   98065 USC00458508
6   98065 USS0021B60S
7   98065 USR0000WFTA
8   98065 USC00451233
9   98146 USW00024234
10  98146 USW00024233
11  98146 USW00094248
12  98146 USC00454169
13  98584 USW00094227
14  98584 USC00451939
15  98584 USC00455086
```

```r
df2 <- 
structure(list(id = c("USW00094290", "USW00094290", "USW00094248", 
"USW00094248", "USW00024234", "USW00024234", "USC00454169", "USC00454169", 
"USC00458508", "USC00458508", "USS0021B60S", "USS0021B60S", "USR0000WFTA", 
"USR0000WFTA", "USC00451233", "USC00451233", "USW00024233", "USW00024233", 
"USW00094227", "USW00094227", "USC00451939", "USC00451939", "USC00455086", 
"USC00455086"), date = structure(c(17167, 17168, 17167, 17168, 
17167, 17168, 17167, 17168, 17167, 17168, 17167, 17168, 17167, 
17168, 17167, 17168, 17167, 17168, 17167, 17168, 17167, 17168, 
17167, 17168), class = "Date"), tmax = c(28, 28, 28, 28, 33, 
28, 33, 28, -11, -28, -17, -50, 11, -17, 0, -11, 28, 11, 44, 
33, 50, 39, 39, 28)), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

df2
# A tibble: 24 x 3
   id          date        tmax
   <chr>       <date>     <dbl>
 1 USW00094290 2017-01-01    28
 2 USW00094290 2017-01-02    28
 3 USW00094248 2017-01-01    28
 4 USW00094248 2017-01-02    28
 5 USW00024234 2017-01-01    33
 6 USW00024234 2017-01-02    28
 7 USC00454169 2017-01-01    33
 8 USC00454169 2017-01-02    28
 9 USC00458508 2017-01-01   -11
10 USC00458508 2017-01-02   -28
# ... with 14 more rows
```

The output should include the unitID, date, and average max. Temp.

```
unitID  date         avg_temp
98008   2009-01-01   30.5
98008   2009-01-02   ...
98008   2009-01-03   ...
```

Comment: Thanks to both of the answers below I was quickly able to achieve this with the following so that i could get a daily average temperature.  ```r  df1  %>%
      left_join(df2, by = c("locationID" = "id")) %>%
      group_by(unitID, date) %>%
      summarise(tmx = mean(tmax, na.rm = TRUE)) ```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `left_join`, `group_by` `unitID` and `locationID` and take `mean` of `tmax`.

```
library(dplyr)

df1  %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c("locationID" = "id")) %>%
  group_by(unitID, locationID) %>%
  summarise(tmx = mean(tmax, na.rm = TRUE))


#   unitID locationID    tmx
#   <chr>  <chr>       <dbl>
# 1 98008  USC00454169  30.5
# 2 98008  USW00024234  30.5
# 3 98008  USW00094248  28  
# 4 98008  USW00094290  28  
# 5 98065  USC00451233  -5.5
# 6 98065  USC00458508 -19.5
# 7 98065  USR0000WFTA  -3  
# 8 98065  USS0021B60S -33.5
# 9 98146  USC00454169  30.5
#10 98146  USW00024233  19.5
#11 98146  USW00024234  30.5
#12 98146  USW00094248  28  
#13 98584  USC00451939  44.5
#14 98584  USC00455086  33.5
#15 98584  USW00094227  38.5
```

---

In base R, we can use `merge` and `aggregate`

```
aggregate(tmax~unitID + locationID, 
          merge(df1, df2, by.x = "locationID", by.y = "id", all.x = TRUE), 
          mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table` join

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[setDT(df2), on = .(locationID = id)][,
    .(tmx = mean(tmax, na.rm = TRUE)), .(unitID, locationID)]
#.   unitID  locationID   tmx
# 1:  98008 USW00094290  28.0
# 2:  98008 USW00094248  28.0
# 3:  98146 USW00094248  28.0
# 4:  98008 USW00024234  30.5
# 5:  98146 USW00024234  30.5
# 6:  98008 USC00454169  30.5
# 7:  98146 USC00454169  30.5
# 8:  98065 USC00458508 -19.5
# 9:  98065 USS0021B60S -33.5
#10:  98065 USR0000WFTA  -3.0
#11:  98065 USC00451233  -5.5
#12:  98146 USW00024233  19.5
#13:  98584 USW00094227  38.5
#14:  98584 USC00451939  44.5
#15:  98584 USC00455086  33.5
```